# how to run another app with specific extras in android

Tags: java, android

Another app added to my launcher home page a shortcut to a specific feature in it.
I want my app to launch directly this feature too.
When I click the shortcut in my launcher it writes in the logcat:

```
 {act=com.xiaomi.smarthome.scene.smarthomelauncher flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.xiaomi.smarthome/.scene.SmartHomeLauncherActivity bnds=[511,1390][700,1599] (has extras)}
```

what I have tried and didn't work:

```
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.xiaomi.smarthome");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("act" , "com.xiaomi.smarthome.scene.smarthomelauncher");
    bundle.putString("flg" , "0x10000000");
    bundle.putString("cmp" , "com.xiaomi.smarthome/.scene.SmartHomeLauncherActivity");
    bundle.putString("bnds" , "[322,1390][511,1599]");
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

any idea?

Comment: It's not extras. `act` is action, `flg` is flags, `cmp` - component name (activity). Don't know what is `bnds`, probably source bounds, in this case you don't need it.

Comment: Like Sergey said-  those aren't the extras, those are the normal parameters for the intent.  The extras weren't printed.  Unless you either reverse engineer the APK or the author documents what the extras are, there's no way to know what they are.